# How do I Get at a Property?

Tags: typescript

I may be overcomplicating this but I have the following situation wherein I need to see if a "ResourceScheduleType" is equal to some number. I think the comments in the code best illustrate what I'm trying to do. For some reason, my "matching" variable does not give me the property I need.. I'd like to move away from using the jQuery grep piece as well.

```
class MyCalendarVM {
    CalendarPoints: MyCalendarPoints[];
}

class MyCalendarPoints {
    ResourceScheduleType: number;
    aDate: string;
}

class MyType {
    MyName: string;
}


$(document).ready(() => {
    $.get("/Calendar/GetMonthCalendar", null, (data: MyCalendarVM) => {
        if (data.CalendarPoints.length == 0) {
            (<any>$('#date')).datepicker();
        } else {
            $(<any>data.CalendarPoints).each(
                (<any>$("#date")).datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        var result = new Array(true, '', null);
                        var matching = <MyCalendarPoints[]>$.grep(data.CalendarPoints, function (event) {
                            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
                        }, false);

                        //TODO: make determination for blue or yellow dot
                        if (matching.length) {
                            var classes = "";

                            // if matching.ResourceScheduleTypeId == 3
                            // classes += "yellowDot";
                            // if matching.ResourceScheduleTypeId == 1 || 2 || 9
                            // classes += " blueDot";
                            result = [true, classes, null];
                        }
                        return result;
                    },
                    onSelect: function (dateText) {
                        var date,
                            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
                            i = 0,
                            event = null;

                        while (i < data.CalendarPoints.length && !event) {
                            date = data.CalendarPoints[i].aDate;

                            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                                event = data.CalendarPoints[i];
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                        if (event) {
                            alert(event.Title);
                        }
                    }
                })
            );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You really need have code to be sufficiently simplified to contain only stuff related to your question. Essentially you're asking people to debug your script for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `matching` is an array, so you need to access it by index before the properties on a specific `MyCalendarPoints` object are available.

```
matching[0].ResourceScheduleTypeId // MyCalendarPoints
```

Not

```
matching.ResourceScheduleTypeId // MyCalendarPoints[]
```

I have gleaned this from looking at your cast:

```
<MyCalendarPoints[]>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add definitions for jQuery and jQuery-UI, you can get rid of all `any`-casts.

```
///<reference path='jquery-1.8.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='jqueryui-1.9.d.ts'/>
```

You also need to change

```
$(<any>data.CalendarPoints).each(
```

to

```
$(data.CalendarPoints).each(() =>
```

since `.each()` expects a function.

You can find the `.d.ts`-files at [Boris Yankov's github](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/Definitions).